# Double pointers - output explanation

Tags: c, double-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int a=1,b=2,c=3; int *p,*q,**r; p=&a;
    r=&q;
    q=&c;
    a=*q+**r;
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",**r,*p,*q); 
    *r=p;
    a=*q+**r;
    printf("w=%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=3 y=6 z=3
w=12
```

I was able to predict the output correctly, but I am not sure whether I have the correct explanation for the output of z.

Please see whether I have the correct understanding:

- Right before `*r=p;` executes, we have `a=6,b=2,c=3`.
- When  `*r=p;` executes, the value at the place to which `r` points to gets changed to `p`.
- Now `r` points to `q` that has address of `c`, so now `q` has address of `a` because `p` points to `a`. So `q` now points to `a`. So `*q` gives 6.
- Since `r` still points to `q`, and `q` points to `a`, `**r` gives 6.
- So `*q + **r = 6+6=12`

Is this the correct explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down:

1. `int a=1,b=2,c=3;`

   ```
   a = 1
   b = 2
   c = 3
   ```
2. `int *p,*q,**r;`

   ```
   p --> ?
   q --> ?
   r --> ? --> ?
   ```
3. `p=&a;`

   ```
   p --> a = 1
   q --> ?
   r --> ? --> ?
   ```
4. `r=&q;`

   ```
   p --> a = 1
   q --> ?
   r --> q --> ?
   ```
5. `q=&c;`

   ```
   p --> a = 1
   q --> c = 3
   r --> q --> c = 3
   ```
6. `a=*q+**r;`, as can be seen from the previous point, we have:

   ```
   a = 3 + 3 = 6
   ```
7. `printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",**r,*p,*q);` prints:

   ```
   x=3 y=6 z=3
   ```
8. `*r=p;`. This is sneaky: since `*r == q`, this changes `q`. This is the same as doing `q=p`. So we get:

   ```
   p --> a = 6
   q --> a = 6
   r --> q --> a = 6
   ```
9. `a=*q+**r;`, as can be seen from the previous point, we have:

   ```
   a = 6 + 6 = 12
   ```
10. `printf("w=%d\n",a);` prints:

    ```
    w=12
    ```

Conclusion: **your explanation is correct**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. *r = p would make the item r points to, q, point to the same address as p, which is &a. 
**r is the same as *q which is the value at &a which is 6.